# types that are assignable to type 'never'

Tags: typescript, interface

In the following example, does anyone know how to write the `field` variable such that it complies with the given interfaces (and thus we shouldn't have to change the interfaces)? Right now I am getting an error saying `Type '{ accountId: string; active: true; }[]' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

```
interface Fields {
    votes: Votes & {
        voters: never;
    };
}

interface Votes {
    self: string;
    votes: number;
    hasVoted: boolean;
    voters: User[];
}

interface User {
    accountId: string;
    active: boolean;
}

const field: Fields = {
    votes: {
        self: "self",
        votes: 0,
        hasVoted: false,
        voters: [
            {
                accountId: "accountId",
                active: true,
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

Comment: yes that's correct - I'll update the question

Comment: What an odd type for them to use... I suspect a TypeScript idiom I'm not familiar with. :-)

Comment: Wild guess: Perhaps this code is pre TypeScript 3.5 and the [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) utility type wasn't available yet. So someone just set the property to `never` using an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#the-omit-helper-type) which were introcuded in 1.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nothing is assignable to `never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#the-never-type), so you'll have to force it with a type assertion. For example:

```typescript
const fields: Fields = {
    votes: {
        self: "self",
        votes: 0,
        hasVoted: false,
        voters: [
            {
                accountId: "accountId",
                active: true,
            },
        ] as Fields["votes"]["voters"], // <=============
    },
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLAgGwCYGdkDeAUMqcgG4D2kuAXMgGrUT4BkhJZXVkUdyICOWgBuTqQC+YiUSKhe8JI2b5iXXFhj1cYKKADmY7ivogArgFsARqPHIAFnFxNI2elcqVMEOCCNkeaH4AVQ0oAG0AXWlZeWhFFFDoDi5EBEozcABJN2QdPRBDO0QwYGF3T29fGKJ0kB1kGAwcfnQsPGQAXhSAkx6uUg1MLWQAIiGYUYAaO2MaegAGGYGyR2dmXPhMDWWVimY+enDZvbU987SM7NzRy8ywHOmT89ISsoh6XTMIXZfkCV+A0iyCcaGaeHCo0CuFGkUhgT4sKmyAA9CjkAAeTrYnG47F2AFEKRAA)